# Is that possible to build ios Framework for support dynamic version of XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I've build a framework which is able to run on xCode 11.4 but it cannot run on XCode version 11.3. 
Is that possible to build ios Framework to support both older or higher version of XCode (Dynamic version of XCode)?
Thanks you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated that it can be open in Xcode 11.4 but not 11.3, I believe its because you have set your project format to be 11.4 compatible. To change that, you can select a lower Xcode project compatibility version such as 11.0, to suit your needs, as shown below.

[image: select Xcode project compatibility]

It's in your project > right sidebar, under Project Documentation.